# Prometheus java/Spring API for fetching metrics

Tags: spring, prometheus, prometheus-java

I need to query for collected metrics in my application and the only way I found to do it is via Prometheus rest api as described here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/ Does any Spring or java api for fetching metrics from Prometheus exist, so that I wouldn't have to implement it from scratch?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/anhdat/prometheus4j

Comment: You could also connect Grafana to prometheus